# Alfresco - Approve task in a workflow

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm integrating an applet on a workflow in the Alfresco. I created a new button `org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/activiti-transitions.ftl` here

```
  ...

    <button onclick="changePDF(); this.disabled=true; return false;"> Change </button>
    <div id="pdfTexto" style="width:1000px;height:1000px"></div>
        <div class="applet">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                deploy();
            </script>
        </div>
    </#if>
```

And this button **change** (through the javascript of the applet) calls the functionality of the applet that is make changes in the file of the respective workflow. After this, I want to put `"Approved"` like the button `accept` standard does. But, I only want to make this after the changes make effect. My applet returns a `"ok"` when the changes are completed (the **POST request** is completed), after this, I want to put `"Approved"` and redirect to the same page that "accept" button redirects. In resume, after "ok", make what the accept button does.

My applet updates the content of an exiting document with:
`http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/upload` ...

How can I make this? Any hints for a better solution then the below?

**Evolution:**
I'm trying to make this:

```
 var form = new FormData();
     form.append("prop_wf_reviewOutcome","Approve");
     form.append("prop_bpm_comment","good");
     form.append("prop_transitions","Next");
     var requestTask = new XMLHttpRequest();
         requestTask[Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getHeader()] = Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken();
         requestTask.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/api/task/"+ taskidVar+ "/formprocessor" + "?" + Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getParameter() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(Alfresco.util.CSRFPolicy.getToken()));
         requestTask.send(form);
```

But lack redirect the page as the "Approve" button.

Comment: what exactly does the applet? Update the property of the document ? Or update its content ?

Comment: Sorry, i forget this information. My applet updates the content of an exiting document. I edit my question. @MarcoAltieri

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you need to define your behaviour:

```
package com.someco.alfresco.policy;

import org.alfresco.model.ContentModel;
import org.alfresco.repo.content.ContentServicePolicies;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.Behaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.JavaBehaviour;
import org.alfresco.repo.policy.PolicyComponent;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceService;
import org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class DocumentUpdatePolicy implements ContentServicePolicies.OnContentUpdatePolicy {
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private PolicyComponent policyComponent;    
    private NodeService nodeService;    

    public void init() {
        this.policyComponent.bindClassBehaviour(
                QName.createQName(NamespaceService.ALFRESCO_URI, "onContentUpdate"),
                ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT,
                new JavaBehaviour(this, "onContentUpdate", Behaviour.NotificationFrequency.EVERY_EVENT));
    }

    @Override
    public void onContentUpdate(NodeRef nodeRef, boolean newContent) {

        logger.debug("Called on: " + nodeRef);
        if (null == nodeRef || !nodeService.exists(nodeRef)) {
            logger.error("Wrong nodeRef");
            /* This can happen in some circumstances */
            /* Do you want to just ignore it or do something ? You decide */
            return;
        }

        /* Here goes the code to update the task */
    }

    public void setPolicyComponent(final PolicyComponent policyComponent) {
        this.policyComponent = policyComponent;
    }

    public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService) {
        this.nodeService = nodeService;
    }


}
```

Than you need to initialise it in your custom Spring context:

```
<bean id="onDocumentUpdatePolicy" class="com.someco.alfresco.policy.DocumentUpdatePolicy">
    <property name="policyComponent">
        <ref bean="policyComponent" />
    </property>
    <property name="nodeService">
        <ref bean="NodeService" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Try this, just to start and then you can add the code for the task

Comment: Hum, I was trying to do in javascript file of the applet..So, I have to make a java class apart right? Where I have to put my custom spring context and this class? Server-side? I'm asking this because in my workflow, I modify the PDF when the workflow is created too and then, only when the applet button is pressed, in each user's task. That is, I just wanted this onContentUpdate fired on user tasks rather than on creating workflow (which is also a content update). There are some kind of restrictions so that it does not fire in the creation of the workflow? I think that is the only problem.

Comment: And one more question... Sorry i'm confused about the funcionality of this. And I have to call this behaviour in the javascript of the applet? My question is, how can I know that "task done" is for the specific user that make the changes? I have to communicate between this and the applet? And to redirect the page? I'm confused about that.

Comment: The behaviour will be called automatically by Alfresco. It is a listener that intercepts events in the repository. The one I wrote, is listening for content update. If the content is updated also in other ways, the behaviour will be called. To avoid this, what you can do is to check that a property is set. For example, you can say that the applet will set a "someco:documentStatus" to "Final". The behaviour will check that the property is set to "Final" before doing anything.

Comment: If you are sure that when the document is in a workflow, only the applet will update it, you do not need the status: you can just check that the document is in a workflow package.

Comment: Before trying to go further, you have to familiarise with behaviours. Do some experiments with the behaviour I wrote.

Comment: When I start workflow, the applet make a change on the content of the document, then, only the applet does. So, I can just check that the document is in a workflow package, right? Because in the creation of the workflow, when I check that the document is in a workflow, if already changed in the creation, i think that works. right?
But the most important... I'm trying but, I think this is not called... I'm trying to make "system.out.println" but I don't see anything... is in the server-side that I have to call this right?I create the java but, where I create the new context?Maybe it's the error

Comment: I tried to create on alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}/context/service-context.xml and then create a module-context.xml inside alfresco/module/${project.artifactId}, to import resource above (service-context.xml) . But this not works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103393/discussion-between-marco-altieri-and-prvs).

Comment: You see anything on pom.xml? I edit my question a Lil bit because of "Approved" instead "task done" and I put on the chat New tries

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103416/discussion-between-marco-altieri-and-prvs).

Comment: Done. I redirect to the page: http://localhost:8080/share/page/task-details?taskId=activiti$23558&nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/fbe95107-a6a4-468b-a0e9-a3eaaad88b80

Thanks ;)